# Column renaming by belongs to checking in mysql query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to write a query something like this to find out fellowships of ms and phd students separetly:

```
select sum(fellowship) as if(ID BELONGS TO #{ms_ids},'ms_fellowship','phd_fellowship') 
from fellowships where id in #{all_ids};
```

Here in the above query I have already built two arrays student_ids and teacher_ids with my ruby code which I get from another table. But the problem is that I cannot figure out how to write the portion of the code where I want to check whether **id belongs to certain array(like in above student_ids array)**.

Answer (score 0):

Join the array of ids, supposing it's an array like `[3, 53, 43, 43]`:

```
# >>>> #{all_ids.join(",")}

select sum(fellowship) as if(ID BELONGS TO #{ms_ids},'ms_fellowship','phd_fellowship') from fellowships where id in (#{all_ids.join(",")});
```